# How can I access functions output across Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have 3 files:

Ingredients.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require('readline');
const stream = require('stream');


const ingredients = () => {
    const instream = fs.createReadStream('ingredients.txt');
    const outstream = new stream;
    const rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

    const listIngredients = {};


    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        let lower = line.toLowerCase();
        listIngredients[lower] = 0; 
    });

    rl.on('close', function () {
        console.log('listIngredients', listIngredients);
    });
}

module.exports = ingredients;
```

cookbook.js:

```
let fs = require("fs");

const book = () => {

    const regex = /\b(\w+)\b/g;

    fs.readFile('cook-book.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

        let book = data;
        let lower = book.toLowerCase();
        let split = lower.match(regex);
        console.log(split);
    });

}
module.exports = book;
```

compare.js

```
const ingredients = require('./ingredients');
const book = require('./book');
```

I'm trying to increase the key values of ingredients every time they are mentioned in the cookbook. I think this should go into a different js file to make it cleaner.

Whilst i can console.log out the information from the above files, I cannot figure out how to actually access the data and make changes to the ingredients object in compare.js?

Comment: ingredients isn't an object, it's a function

Comment: Both files are read async, and the functions you're requiring in compare.js don't return anything. So with your current code, you cannot access either. You have to either switch to Sync versions of readFile, or use Promises / async+await.

Comment: Is switching to readFileSynce as easy as this:
let data = fs.readFileSync('oliver-twist.txt', "utf-8");
const regex = /\b(\w+)\b/g;


let lower = data.toLowerCase();
let split = lower.match(regex);
console.log(split);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as others noticed your `ingredients` and `book` variables are functions having required information inside their scope and not returning it outside. to fix it, you have to return values.

as you're working with asynchronous stuff, your functions should be wrapped into `Promise`'s to handle the flow correctly.

this code should help you:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const { Writable } = require('stream');
const fsp = fs.promises;

// ingredients.js
const getIngredients = async () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const instream = fs.createReadStream('ingredients.txt');
  const outstream = new Writable();
  const rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

  const listIngredients = {};

  rl.on('line', line => {
    const lower = line.toLowerCase();
    listIngredients[lower] = 0;
  });
  rl.on('error', reject);
  rl.on('close', () => resolve(listIngredients));
});

// cookbook.js
const getBookContent = async () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const wordRegEx = /\b(\w+)\b/g;
    const book = await fsp.readFile('cook-book.txt', 'utf8')
    const lower = book.toLowerCase();
    return resolve(lower.match(wordRegEx));
  } catch (error) {
    return reject(error);
  }
});

// compare.js
(async () => {
  const ingredients = await getIngredients();
  const words = await getBookContent();
  console.log(ingredients);
  console.log(words);
})();
```

the names of functions have been change for better representations of their instances.

i've also used an `async` [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to use `async/await` syntax, however you can still work with `Promise`s themselves

Comment: Can you please explain how I import the ingredients and cookbook files into a seperate compare.js? I'm trying to use a module export but cannot figure it out?

Comment: try `exports.<name> = <something>` to export your functions or `module.exports = { <name>: <something> }` if you want it this way. read more at 
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Comment: Its calling it within the compare.js file that I'm struggling with, i've got exports.<name> = <something> on both files. Importing it within compare.js is where don't know the correct way of doing it so when i node compare.js it runs?

Comment: in `compare.js` use `const { getBookContent } = reqiure('./cookbook.js')` while in `cookbook.js` you should have `exports.getBookContent = getBookContent;` and `getBookContent` is defined previously